# How to set 256colors in xfce4-terminal 0.6.3 that is using the fish shell, always for all users

Tags: terminal, fish

How to set 256colors in xfce4-terminal 0.6.3 that is using the fish shell, always for all users ? Can't find this info anywhere and it's getting hard.

Answer (score 1):

The file `/etc/fish/config.fish` is the right place for systemwide configuration for all users.

You can use something like:

```
if begin; status --is-interactive; and test "$COLORTERM" = xfce4-terminal ; end
    set -gx TERM xterm-256color
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, that would be setting `TERM` to some appropriate terminal description (such as [`vte-256color`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-vte-256color)).  According to the [`fish` FAQ](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html), you can set variables in

```
 ~/.config/fish/config.fish
```

but it does not mention a standard configuration for the *system*.

The various [configuration files](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#initialization) are read only at shell startup time, unless you source them (with **`.`**), e.g.,

```
~/.config/fish/config.fish
/usr/share/fish/config.fish
/etc/fish/config.fish
```

This is typical of most shells: they have no way to notify other running instances that they should update an environment variable.  So you can either restart the running shell, or reset `TERM` (directly with an `export`, or by sourcing a script).

Comment: won't work the only thing that works in changing the tput colors value is entering `export TERM=xterm-256color` but it's useless since you have to restart the terminal. `set TERM=xterm-256color` in `/etc/fish/config.fish` doesn't have an effect and tput color still gets 8 after restarting the terminal